# How do I make a sound hold for a long time?

Tags: iphone, sdk

I'm making a music app with a piano, but I need to be able to hold the sound long or short. So like if I hold a button it will start playing the sound but if I let go it stops WITH A FADE, so however long I hold the button down that is how long the sound will play (that is until the sound ends).

How do I do this in the iPhone SDK?

Comment: Do you have trouble with knowing how long the user has pressed the button for? Do you have a problem with knowing how to make sound fade starting at a given time?

Comment: I dont know how to make the sound start and stop when the users finger touches and realeases and i dont know how to fade out

Answer (score 0):

`UIButton` is a subclass of `UIResponder`, which has methods to tell it when a touch begins or ends - making use of those should get you what you need.

Comment: Can you explain more becasue im still kinda new the code im using now to play ANY sound is... how would i set it up?

- (IBAction)snare {

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Snare" ofType:@"mp3"];
 AVAudioPlayer* theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
 theAudio.delegate = self;
 [theAudio play];
 
 
}